# Why won't this compile (link) with the Q_OBJECT macro in place?

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qobject

I made a prototype of a project with PyQt and made it work there, now I'm trying to convert it to C++ and am having some problems.

If I don't put the Q_OBJECT macro in, it compiles and works, but if I comment it out, I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "vtable for MapView", referenced from:
      MapView::~MapView()in mapview.o
      MapView::~MapView()in mapview.o
      MapView::MapView(QObject*)in mapview.o
      MapView::MapView()in mapview.o
  "MapView::staticMetaObject", referenced from:
      MapView::MapView(QObject*)in mapview.o
      MapView::MapView()in mapview.o
```

Here's the header:

```
#ifndef MAPVIEW_H
#define MAPVIEW_H

#include <QtGui>
#include <QObject>

class MapView : public QGraphicsScene
{
    //Q_OBJECT

public:
    MapView();
    explicit MapView(QObject *parent = 0);
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *mappixmap;
    ~MapView();

private:
    bool dragging;
    float offsetX, offsetY, downoffsetX, downoffsetY;

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);

};

#endif // MAPVIEW_H
```

Secondary question is will Bad Things happen if I just omit the Q_OBJECT macro here?

And yes, I'm aware of that it's stupid to call a QGraphicsScene a "view".

Comment: I will post function implementations per request, I just don't want to post everything here at once...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This kind of errors usually happen when you add the `Q_OBJECT` macro and forget to rerun `moc`. If you use `qmake`, just run `make qmake` after you added the macro.

As for your second question: you won't be able to use signals/slots (among other things) without the `Q_OBJECT` macro. See the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) for more information about this.

Comment: Thanks, rerunning qmake indeed this fix this! I don't really need to use signal and slots here, just receive calls to the event handlers I've defined. But I still want to do things the proper way.

Comment: @teukkam, If your classes are inherited from `QObject`, you will need `Q_OBJECT` macro...

Comment: @liaK: No, you only need it for signals/slots and some other things. See the link in my answer.

Comment: Obviously I don't need that macro, because the program works as expected even if I omit it. I just like to have it there so the code looks like how one would expect it to look in the typical case.

Comment: @ Job, http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/metaobjects.html Check out this link.. From the docs, **we strongly recommend that all subclasses of QObject use the Q_OBJECT macro regardless of whether or not they actually use signals, slots, and properties.**

Comment: @liaK: I agree it's best practice to use the macro. I just meant it is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation of running QMake again! This issue has been tripping me up too, albeit with a different codebase involved (obviously). :)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I tried to compile `QDeviceWatcher` on *Linux* and I get the same error WRT `QDeviceWatcherPrivate` class, which declaration can be found in `qdevicewatcher_p.h` and definition in `qdevicewatcher_linux.cpp` (on *Linux*).

I use *cmake* as build system and my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project("QDeviceWatcher" LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Network)

set(SOURCES)
list(APPEND SOURCES "qdevicewatcher.cpp")
if(WINCE)
    list(APPEND SOURCES "qdevicewatcher_wince.cpp")
elseif(WIN32)
    list(APPEND SOURCES "qdevicewatcher_win32.cpp")
elseif(APPLE)
    list(APPEND SOURCES "qdevicewatcher_mac.cpp")
elseif(UNIX)
    list(APPEND SOURCES "qdevicewatcher_linux.cpp")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "no supported platform detected")
endif()

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ".")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Qt5::Core Qt5::Network)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS YES
    )
```

As you can see in `add_library` I only provide `*.cpp` files. I suspect, that *cmake* runs *Meta object compiler* and looks through all the sources, maybe except `#include` dependencies, which filenames (w/o extension) not match `*.cpp`'s filenames (just assumption), for the `QObject/QWidget/...` bases and `Q_OBJECT` macro. And I think `cmake` missed `qdevicewatcher_p.h` to look through and run *MOC* against it.

After I added the "qdevicewatcher_p.h" to the list of sources the error is ceased to exist.