# Qt connect can't find slot

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use `QObject::connect` to start a slot from after a thread finishes.

My class definition is:

```
class Test : public QWidget
{
public:
  Test(QWidget *parent=0);
private slots:
  void do_work();
  void show_box();
private:
  QFuture<void> work_thread;
  QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;
};
```

I tried the following code:

```
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(show_box()));
```

But when I run the compiled binary it says:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QWidget::show_box()
```

I've also tried

```
QFutureWatcher<void> *watcher;
connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, this, &Test::show_box);
```

But it exits with a segmentation fault.

Comment: You need to use the Q_OBJECT macro for signals and slots to work. I would expect moc to issue a warning about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Qt signal and slot not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645898/c-qt-signal-and-slot-not-firing)

Answer (score 3):

Missing `Q_OBJECT` inside `Test`.

[What does the Q_OBJECT macro do? Why do all Qt objects need this macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368584/qt-question-what-does-the-q-object-macro-do-why-do-all-qt-objects-need-this-ma)

If you don't have it, signals/slots don't work.

```
class Test : public QWidget{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Test(QWidget *parent=0);
private slots:
  void do_work();
  void show_box();
private:
  QFuture<void> work_thread;
  QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;
};
```