# C++ - Undefined reference to `vtable

Tags: c++, qt

I was wondering why I was getting this error:
undefined reference to `vtable for BaseRenderer'

I tried searching around but cannot seem to figure this out. I've tried getting rid of the virtual function, removing the constructor, etc.

My BaseRenderer.h

```
class BaseRenderer : public Renderer
{
 Q_OBJECT

    public:
        BaseRenderer();
        BaseRenderer(QWidget *parent);
        void paintGL();

        virtual ~BaseRenderer();

 public slots:
  void loadDialog();

 signals:

    protected:
        Mesh loadMesh(string fileName);

    private:

        OBJParser objParser;
        Mesh baseTerrain;

};
```

My BaseRenderer.cpp

```
BaseRenderer::BaseRenderer()              <------ Error leads me here
{
}

BaseRenderer::BaseRenderer(QWidget *parent) : Renderer(parent)
{

}

BaseRenderer::~BaseRenderer()
{
    //dtor
}
```

How would I go about getting rid of this issue? I also hear it may be the compiler...?
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: what are the parameters passed to the  compiler?

Comment: @John - it's a Qt macro, which means this source file has to be run through a separate Qt tool (`moc.exe`) for a bunch of code to be generated for Qt-specific behaviors like slots and signals.

Comment: @birryree:  Ah. I have no familiarity with Qt whatsoever, so I'll bow out of this one

Comment: Or, if you use qmake, it generates the moc commands in your makefile for you.

Comment: Check that your header is listed in the HEADERS section in the .pro file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Q_OBJECT is in the parent class, Renderer, you don't have to also include it BaseRenderer. Just get rid of Q_OBJECT and it should work :)

Comment: It works for me. can you elaborate more why removing Q_OBJECT solve this? I subclass thing from QWidget

Comment: If you add slots in a subclass, this doesn't work. See e.g. https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/5723#issuecomment-466628042

Comment: Also, some docs (search the web on this) suggest that `Q_OBJECT` should always be present in `QObject` direct or indirect subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

See '[What does it mean that the "virtual table" is an unresolved external?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.10)' in the C++ FAQ Lite.

Answer (score 1):

I think this highly unhelpful message is really complaining about you not providing definitions for the other functions in your `BaseRenderer` class, as your `baseRenderer.cpp` file seems to only have the constructor and destructors.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you implement all declared methods, especially the slot. Then check that your header is listed in the HEADERS section in the .pro file and then run qmake.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it's the same issue I had when asking this question: [Why won't this compile (link) with the Q_OBJECT macro in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607262/why-wont-this-compile-link-with-the-q-object-macro-in-place)

Try rerunning qmake like paxdiablo and Tobias suggest.